# HDMI through USB-C

Tags: hdmi, usb-c, dock, dongle

I am trying to connect an HDMI monitor to USB-C port on my computer so that I can have dual screens.

The port is SuperSpeed USB Type-C and the HDMI monitor standard is HDMI 1.4.  I am using a dock.

No picture shows.  Wondering if it is even possible to do this -- however it works on my laptop that has a thunderbolt connection.

Comment: You do understand that HDMI is not compatible with USB Type-C?  DisplayPort and USB Type-C are compatible

Comment: Did not know that...

Comment: I read that USB-C Alt mode may work?

Comment: correction, it can but only if the device supports Alternative Mode

Comment: "Superspeed" USB is 3.0 or early 3.1, It can only carry video of any type if it also has a DP symbol (DisplayPort). USB-C (of any kind) cannot carry HDMI without an adaptor. Alt mode is DisplayPort.